# Angular2 dynamic routing providers

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i want to provide value of [router-link],path,component,and as dynamically.

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/SettingStudent']">Settings</a></li>

{ path: '/settings', component:Settings, name:'SettingStudent' }
```

in this example i provide static values but how to provide dynamically like following ?

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/{{SettingStudent}}']">{{Settings}}</a></li>

{ path: '/{{settings}}', component:{{Settings}}, name:'{{SettingStudent}}' }
```

is it possible in angular2 ? if yes then how ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<li><a [routerLink]="['/' + SettingStudent]">{{Settings}}</a></li>

{ path: '/' + settings, component: `${Settings}`, name: `${SettingStudent}` }
```

Comment: [router-link] is working fine but except this nothing is working in my case although your code does't create any error.

Comment: here is working plnkr of that code  http://plnkr.co/edit/R8zAuNJssjq3UDQdOGNd?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In class, declare variable:

```
private routes: any[] = [
    {
        name: 'Asset Tag',
        path: ['SysInfoAssetTag']
    },
    {
        name: 'System',
        path: ['SysInfoSystem']
    }
]
```

Then in view

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let route of routes"><a [routerLink]="route.path">{{route.name}}</a> </li>
</ul>
```