# How to assign dynamic router in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a issue when try assgin router:

```
item.href = 'address';
item.text = 'click to Address';
```

and in template:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['{{item.href}}']" >{{item.text}}</a>
```

But it is still error: 
"Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at...."

Please help me assign router in template is dynamic.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797229/angular2-dynamic-routing-providers

Comment: I think you should try `[routerLink]="[item.href]"` which will evaluate item.href value directly there

Comment: It worked. Thanks :)

Comment: @PankajParkar why didn't you in the first place? :s

Comment: @iH8 now it is there :p :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't `{{}}` interpolation there to get evaluated value, you could directly use `item.href` to fill `href` value.

**Code**

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[item.href]" >{{item.text}}</a>
```